# Backslash-n not interpreted as newline when printed?

Tags: python

Given a simple map:

```
combinations  = {'a':11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13}
```

Let us print its entries on separate lines:

```
print('Combinations: ', '\n'.join(str(c) for c in combinations.iteritems()))
```

.. or maybe not ..

```
('Combinations: ', "('a', 11)\n('c', 13)\n('b', 12)")
```

Why is the `\n` not interpreted as a newline here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re using Python 2 rather than Python 3, so the `print` is actually printing a tuple. Converting a tuple to a string applies `repr` to its elements.

Either

- switch to Python 3,
- use `__future__` to get the print function in Python 2,

  ```
  from __future__ import print_function
  ```
- or remove the tuple.

  ```
  print 'Combinations: ', '\n'.join(str(c) for c in combinations.iteritems())
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the question, however it is not an issue with print() or '\n', see the follow example:

```
print('first\nsecond\nthird')
first
second
third
```

If you want to print a key,value to each line, you can do the follow

```
print('\n'.join(str(c[0]) + ": " + str(c[1]) for c in combinations.iteritems()))
a: 11
c: 13
b: 12
```